# How to configure package stellar-horizon-postgres?

Tags: horizon

Using `stellar-quickstart`, I am able to install, then start and sync `stellar-core`. However, my attempts to install `stellar-horizon` fail with the following message:

```
  Package stellar-horizon-postgres is not configured yet.
```

How to configure it? Thanks in advance. More info, if required:

```
alec@alec-MS-7596 ~/product $ sudo systemctl stop stellar-core
alec@alec-MS-7596 ~/product $ sudo systemctl mask stellar-core
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/stellar-core.service to /dev/null.
alec@alec-MS-7596 ~/product $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install stellar-horizon
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]            
Hit:6 https://apt.stellar.org/public stable/ InRelease                                
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Fetched 325 kB in 1s (306 kB/s)                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
stellar-horizon is already the newest version (0.17.4-45).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up stellar-horizon-postgres (0.1-5) ...
2019/04/05 11:30:38 exec failed: pq: relation "gorp_migrations" already exists
dpkg: error processing package stellar-horizon-postgres (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stellar-quickstart:
 stellar-quickstart depends on stellar-horizon-postgres; however:
  Package stellar-horizon-postgres is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package stellar-quickstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                   Errors were encountered while processing:
 stellar-horizon-postgres
 stellar-quickstart
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It looks like you have an older copy of the Horizon database already installed. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I checked the database, it has only one table, and the table has 0 rows. This observation, and the fact that the initial installation failed with the same message (Package stellar-horizon-postgres is not configured yet.), led me to decide not to remove the database.

Comment: The failure message above looks like an edge case bug around the fact that the migration table exists (and the installation assumes it shoudn't). If you don't have any data here, you could try removing the DB and trying again.

Comment: You are absolutely right,  ire_and_curses! Thanks a lot for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

All it took was to drop the `horizon` database! Many thanks to **ire_and_curses** for the tip! Steps below outline the fix.

```
  458  sudo -u stellar psql -c 'DROP DATABASE horizon' postgres
  459  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install stellar-horizon
  460  sudo -u stellar psql -d horizon
  462  sudo systemctl unmask stellar-core
  463  sudo systemctl start stellar-core
  464  sudo stellar-core-cmd info # wait for "state" : "Synced!"
  465  sudo systemctl start stellar-horizon
  466  sudo systemctl status stellar-horizon
```

Comment: Glad this worked! FYI I've raised an issue to check this out: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/1111

Answer (score 1):

@alec-missine, @ire_and_curses Thank you both for reporting this issue!

The `stellar-horizon` package does not create a `horizon` database, creating the `horizon` db is handled by the `stellar-horizon-postgres` package. This is by design.

The edge case you encountered exists because although the `stellar-horizon` package doesn't create the `horizon` db it does run the Horizon migrations as part of it's `stellar-horizon.postinst configure` maintainer script step. We do this to ensure seamless schema migrations during installs/upgrades of Horizon.

I believe that in this instance, you must have created a `horizon` database but not run `stellar-horizon-cmd db init` to create the db schema. When you installed the `stellar-horizon` package it would have attempted to run the migrations on an empty `horizon` db (creating the `gorp_migrations` table only).

When you subsequently installed the `stellar-quickstart` package the database already existed but not the schema which caused the installation of stellar-horizon-postgres to fail, cascading all the way back to the `stellar-quickstart` installation failure.

Going forwards, I have modified the `stellar-horizon` postinst script to check if the schema has been created prior to running `db migrate up` ([#43](https://github.com/stellar/packages/pull/43)),  this should prevent this from occurring again.