# (Install Error) Package stellar-horizon-postgres is not configured yet

Tags: stellar-core, postgres

**1-** I cannot install stellar horizon it gives an error. I tried this solution https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/2400 but it didn't work.

---

**2-** I tried this solution https://github.com/stellar/packages/issues/42#issuecomment-483617477

**stellar-horizon-cmd db init** command gives an error.

```
2019/10/08 10:27:53 pq: must be owner of extension plpgsql handling 1_initial_schema.sql
```

---

**3-** I tried db migrate up. It gives an error.

**sudo -u stellar /usr/bin/stellar-horizon --apply-migrations**

```
2019/10/08 10:31:00 could not apply migrations: pq: must be owner of extension plpgsql handling 1_initial_schema.sql
```

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install stellar-horizon

```
Setting up stellar-horizon-postgres (0.1-6) ...
2019/10/08 10:10:29 pq: must be owner of extension plpgsql handling 1_initial_schema.sql
dpkg: error processing package stellar-horizon-postgres (--configure):
 installed stellar-horizon-postgres package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stellar-quickstart:
 stellar-quickstart depends on stellar-horizon-postgres; however:
  Package stellar-horizon-postgres is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package stellar-quickstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stellar-horizon-postgres
 stellar-quickstart
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```